# Is possible to control Meteor's Reactivity?

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe, reactive-programming

When a client subscribes to a publish, I'm aware of 2 options: {reactive:true (default)} and {reactive:false}.

If we're using Meteor, it's very likely that we want to use reactivity but sometimes I don't need the updates to be in realtime but near to it. How can I set a interval refresh rate for the pub/sub?

Another scenario: I've, let's say, 300 clients subscribed to a publication, the data changes and all the clients get the DDP change message at the same time. Can I create some sort of delay here between each client update? I don't want an high load on the CPU, users notice that the application isn't responding as fast as usual.

You might be asking yourself: Why this guy wants to do this? When you start to get a lot of clients, the application can quickly become slower because of all the real time updates. In my scenario I don't need real time updates but some close to it. Example: 10 seconds refresh rate.

Comment: I bet it would be possible to use an observer and the low level publication added/changed/removed messages to queue up several messages and send them in chunks at a periodic interval. I have no idea if this would actually help with the scalability of the application though... You're still eventually sending the same amount of messages.

Comment: There isn't a way to slow the DDP messages as far as I know, Meteor uses sock.js for DDP.

If you want to slow down the UI updates, you could create a local collection, and use a timer to sync the local collection with the server collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic idea (untested, sorry for errors, but you get the idea):

```js
var CatsProxy = new Meteor.Collection('CatsProxy')

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    var Cats = new Meteor.Collection('Cats') // private, on server only

    /* ... something causes Cats objects to be updated every half second ... */

    // outside of a reactive context:
    setInterval(function() {
        var cat = Cats.find({_id: 123})
        CatsProxy.update({_id: cat._id}, cat);
    }, 60000) // once a minute

    Meteor.publish("cats", function () {
        return CatsProxy.find({_id: 123});
    });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.subscribe("cats");

    Template.cats.helpers({
        cat: function() {
            // this is reactive
            return CatsProxy.find({_id: 123})
        }
    })
}
```

And now the `cats` template only updates once per minute instead of twice per second.

Comment: This solution is highly inefficient. The questions is about delay the update on a client basis, not on a collection basis. Updating the mongodb database every minute is a sure shoot in foot, CatsProxy is not an anonymous collection in your example. This is a self DDoS attack, you'll flood the server with useless DDP calls.

Comment: @Mário I agree, but nonetheless it was extremely simple to do. Also, note that the setInterval should run on the server (updated answer) and only the CatsProxy published to the client, thus there won't be DDP flooding. Lastly, if you could provide a better answer, that'd be nice and helpful for everyone!

Comment: At least, I *think* there shouldn't be DDP flooding since in my updated answer we're only publishing a single cat, and the client only accesses CatsProxy. If there *is* DDP flooding, then this is a security problem in Meteor which I would think they've already handled.